# Spam sent from stolen address book

Tags: email

Over the weekend at least three of my wife's email contacts received a spam message sent from her name and the user part of her email address, but a different domain name. The spam messages look like:

```
From: xxx@maggioreosp.novara.it
To: <Friend> friends@real.address

Hi Friend

http://spam.link



Friend
xxx@yahoo.co.uk


Sent from my iPhone

---
El software de antivirus Avast ha analizado este correo electrónico en busca de virus.
https://www.avast.com/antivirus

This email has been protected by YAC (Yet Another Cleaner) http://www.yac.mx
```

It's clear that her email contact list has been accessed in some way. It doesn't look like the spam is being sent from her account, just that here email address and contacts are being used.

We were in Dublin airport at the weekend and did use the free wifi there, but I assume that as she accesses her email through the standard Yahoo Mail iPhone app that it was secure.

We have immediately changed her email password. Is there anything else we can do to try and determine the source of this leak?

Comment: Unless the spam was actually sent from her computer, which you should be able to tell from e-mail headers. Then these answers would provide some information http://superuser.com/questions/725234/how-do-scammers-get-your-contacts-when-they-send-emails-that-appear-to-come-from

Comment: The other thing you might consider would be to switch email providers.  I have seen more problems with yahoo than with most other providers.